# How can I unload a dll in order to delete it after a MEF recomposition?

Tags: c#, mef, composition

1. With MEF, I compose my DLL
2. I work with my DLL
3. I recompose without this DLL
4. I want to delete it // => it doesn't work

How can I unload a dll in order to delete it after a MEF recomposition in which this dll is not composed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not unload a DLL/assembly. Only an AppDomain.

Comment: Ok so how can I 'connect' an AppDomain to MEF composition ?

Comment: As I undestand from some podcasts is that Glenn said that you can put in another one and the new one will be populated to your imports - the only one downside is that you'll have the first one still in memory (until you shutdown your app)

Answer (score 0):

> Ok so how can I 'connect' an AppDomain to MEF composition ?

MEF doesnt provide infrastructure to do that, unfortunately. You'd have to bake your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to insert on catalog one Object Assembly like this:

```
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(directoryPath, ItemPlugin)));
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(assembly));
```

You can Delete the file later...